# Reduce audio signal from TV when volume exceeds a certain level

Tags: audio, tv, volume

I hate how loud action scenes are in movies, compared to how low the talking parts are.

My TV is currently connecting to some speakers with a jackstick.
Is it possible to measure the volume with something like an Arduino and reduce the signal when it exceeds a certain amount, but without losing signal integrity or quality.
And if possible, how would I go about it?

I have seen a YouTube video from a guy called GreatScott, where he solves this with a microphone and sends IF signal to the tv, which then turns the volume down. I'm not a fan of this solution however, as I would like a possible solution to be "behind-the-scenes".

Comment: Feed the audio through a compressor or limiter? These already exist so they don't need to be built.

Comment: I seem to remember some devices made for that purpose, but marketed as turning down the volume during loud commercials.  Arduino + IR blaster sounds like overkill unless you are already using it for something else (universal remote etc).

Comment: There are a couple of obvious ways to solve this. 1. Invest in audio processing equipment that divides multi-channel source material into separate channels and allows independent volume control; 2. utilize a compressor/limiter. The question is too broad to provide a definitive "correct" answer and thus is not a good fit for Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

Sure an audio compressor will work. If you can access the speaker wires you can place a small incandescent lamp in series with the speaker. When the volume is normal the filament resistance is low. Choose a small lamp with a DCR of say 2 ohms approx. High sound levels will heat the filament increasing DCR tending to soft limit the sound level. I have used a standard 6.3 volt 0.3 amp pilot lamp to make a poor man's compressor.